# CouchDB for widely scattered sites

Tags: couchdb, couchbase

We are developing a scientific site where:
* one authoritative source of data (master)
* 150+ edge servers scattered around the world (clients)
* potential 5K mobile users connecting to the edge servers (sub-clients)

We need to replicate geospatial data (each document about a few hundred bytes) from the master and distribute it around the globe.
Many edge servers and as well as the mobile will only be occasionally connected. Bandwidth might be very low.

The entire dataset will probably grow to about 200GB, but it can be segmented into smaller geospatial sets for smaller trickle replication.

Data will largely be static. Far less than 1% changes need to be propogated.

Our reading is that CouchDB might be well suited for this. Is there anything we are missing?

- Since data is only changed at the origin, dealing with replication
  conflict made pretty simple
- GeoSpatial search is now supported via GeoCouch (not as good as the PostGIS database we currently use, but
  probably good enough)
- CouchDB indexes should assist given that the data has a low churn rate
- We don't care about low-latency transactions, (data update is slow)
- GeoJSON is a pretty good match for our data type
- We really want the free replication
- We do want fast local search of the data (based on spatial and other features, will we get this?). Speed is measured by human performance, e.g. google search, not in terms of massive automated search
- We would be concerned about corruption and failure detection. But it seem a dump and reload the DB could be done in the case of catastrophe at an edge server, right?

Is there something else we should be looking at (e.g. couchbase, )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main question to put here is if you are going to use filtered replication or not. This is the weakest point of an otherwise beautiful CouchDB.

The problem is that if your scattered servers and, most importantly, clients are going to only replicate a portion of data, you will need to set up filter function, which is not indexed. Upon new client connection it will run against 200 GB of documents, and you don't want to be there waiting until it finishes, believe me...

In the above case the solution would be Couchbase + SyncGateway, or some custom view based replication layer (which is also an option given that you are not going to have many changes, so you may simplify it)

On the other hand, given the fact that you have only one way replication you may find out that you are not gaining that much from CouchDB sync mechanism, and then it will mean that the same result may well be achieved with any other clustered database like even ElasticSearch, which has stunning query performance, binary internal sharding protocol, hot node insertion and is really fun to work with

Couchbase, btw, also uses binary replication mechanism which will be more efficient than CouchDB, as long as the CouchDB protocol is not utilized for bidirectional data exchange and conflict resolution.

Comment: Excellent. This helps me focus my research. The GeoData is not highly interconnected. It should be possible to divide it into separate databases ( by region, type of data etc.) Then to sink parts. But can you point me to anything talking about the replication protocol. Let's say one DB has 50,000 objects. If the master changes 5 items, how expensive is the replication (assume object size of 1KB  on average). [i.e. I think we can avoid filtered replication]

Comment: Not sure if I have understood the question, however I will try to answer. The replication will only transfer changed documents, so the overhead will be roughly equal to the total size of changed documents. It tracks document revisions as a whole, not as diffs. My favorite reading about replication, although a bit technical, is [here](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios/wiki/Guide:-Replication/88148094df2df99a75a84733b91d905ec841b769); make sure to check out the Further Reading section below

Comment: That was a good site, you pick good sources. Two more follow ups (1) should I also look at Mongo Replication, or other DBs with replication? (2) What I also am getting a sense is that CouchDB does something with indexes that allows for search speed-up and aggregates (reductions?) where data is largely stable, and only a few incremental data changes. Any pointers to tech articles on this? coutapp.com/articles/2011/01/20/couchdb-in-production

Comment: Any (almost) no sql database provides the map/reduce interface to indexing its data. Some also provide fancy syntax allowing for sql like queries, but under the hood map and possibly reduce is what is happening there. Even elasticsearch, which is using lucene, can be thought to use a kind of sophisticated map function to create numerous views to the data.

Comment: Regarding replication, your case is rather straightforward, so any working replication solution will do, even MySQL master slave. You relaxed too many constraints, so it is hard to suggest something specific. Same about your research request, sounds like you know the keywords to search for, and you should do that. I will not answer any better than mr Google. If you think that my answer and comments are helpful you are welcome to accept it and ask something else when you come up with a clearly formulated problem. Cheers and good luck!